# How to prevent page refresh after sending email?

Tags: php, html, email

I made a landing site with a email form.

Every time I click submit, whether the form is completely filled out or not, the page refreshes and goes to the top.

How can I not letting it refresh and still send the mail?

If that's not possible, how do I automatically go back to the contact section/div after the page refresh?

Comment: did you try to use Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what submit buttons do. They submit the form, which refreshes the page. Instead, try binding an AJAX handler to your button:

```
// using jquery
button.on("click", function(e) {
    // handler here
    $.post(/* send data somewhere, e.g. email.php */
        blah blah blah
    );
});
```

Then, at email.php:

```
$message = $_POST["message"];
// etc
```

Comment: Just got into web dev, had a little experience with AJAX, so I didn't even think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since your question does not have javascript tag you can use form target:

```
<form action="email_save.php" method="post" target="some_iframe">
  ...
</form>

<iframe name="some_iframe" src=""></iframe>
```